# How do you export a database schema from SQL Server Management Studio to Excel?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms, sql-server-2014

As part of a web migration process, a vendor has asked for our database schema without the data records (for confidential purposes). They want a MS Excel file with each database table. I am completely new to working with databases. Is there an easy way to do this in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio?

Comment: Out of interest, why did they need this in Excel?

Comment: Since I've landed here searching for a generic way on how to export schema into Excel, I'd like to submit the solution which helped me: https://www.bluelabellabs.com/blog/how-to-export-the-schema-of-a-sql-server-mysql-postgres-oracle-database-to-a-csv/

@DavidAtkinson: In my case, the only way to exchange and work on such information between two totally separate legal entities of financial institutions happened to be via Excel. People without knowledge of SQL or DBMS had to work with the structural information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can link your server as Data Source in Excel and then run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

This will export data into Excel

How to connect SQL server to Excel: 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-SQL-Server-database-to-your-workbook-22c39d8d-5b60-4d7e-9d4b-ce6680d43bad

Or if database is not that big then just run it in Management Studio and copy-paste the result to Excel

Comment: Hi the.Legend, thank you for this answer! I think this points me in exactly the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

I needed a similar solution, but with tables and column information too.
We needed to translate a database to another language, including table and column names. This job was done by a translator that known nothing about SQL and Database stuff, but knows Excel.

This SQL did the job:

```
SELECT *
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS CO
 WHERE CO.TABLE_CATALOG = 'YOUR DATABASE'
 ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
```

*The coolest thing is that it keep the column order as shown in Management Studio, to the result set.*